# PYTHON - How to remove certain rows with unwanted data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to remove some rows that have a value that I'm not interested in analysing.

```
Aerogenerador  Cause               DateOn            DateOFF
A0201          Windturbine Pause   02/01/2021 10:00  02/01/2021 10:05
A0202          Windturbine STOP    02/01/2021 10:00  02/01/2021 10:05
A0202          High Temperature DE 02/01/2021 10:00  02/01/2021 10:05
```

So I need to remove the causes that have Windturbine Pause and Windturbine STOP
Expected result:

```
Aerogenerador  Cause               DateOn            DateOFF
A0202          High Temperature DE 02/01/2021 10:00  02/01/2021 10:05
```

Comment: simple indexing should work. `df = df[df['cause'] != ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two Options**
**First Option**

```
rlist = ['Windturbine Pause', 'Windturbine STOP']
df = df.query('Cause not in @rlist')
df
```

**Second Option** If we don't need extra variable

```
df = df.query('Cause not in ["Windturbine Pause", "Windturbine STOP"]')
df
```

**Output**

```
    Aerogenerador   Cause   DateOn  DateOFF
2   A0202   High Temperature DE 02/01/2021 10:00    02/01/2021 10:05
```

#### Edit

Remove all rows with String `Windturbine`

```
df = df[~df.Cause.str.contains("Windturbine")]
df
```